# Docker Network inside a container partially working

Tags: php, networking, docker

I have running the "`FROM php:5.6-apache`" container with my own php application. That works. But one part didn't. 
My application can not use the network.

If i run manualy

```
docker run -t -i myapp ping 8.8.8.8 it
```

that works great. But if my app does it like

```
$ping = exec("ping -c 1 -s 64 -t 64 8.8.8.8");
```

then it doesen't.

Jan

Comment: does `docker logs your_container` or `docker events` show anything interesting?

Comment: No. Logs show the logs from apache/php (everything standard) and events shows nothing.

Comment: so `docker exec -it mycontainer bash` and start debugging like you would on a LInux server

Comment: This works also. I can ping and access the network. But the running container doesent... or in other words - it seems like my php app doesent.

Comment: so while inside your container check `netstat -an` various `lsof` , also `ps -ef` and some specific PHP debugging, good hunt

Comment: I think (but i just begin with docker) - this cant bring me a solution, because ... like described above - this works fine. But ps -ef gives me only this (2 running procs):
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 12:00 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash
root        11     1  0 12:00 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef